# How to track time spent on mobile app views

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, analytics, azure-application-insights

On my iOS and Android clients i need to analyse "how much time spent my users on app views/activities and the app total"

Currently Google Analytics, Visual Studio Application Insights and Facebook App Events are integrated to my clients and i can get figures from this platforms but i couldn't find data on this platforms to analyse "usage time of my views" so i can tell which part of my apps used how long by my users and the app total in a given time period.

So what app analytics platform i can integrate to get "time spent on view/activities and the app total" for my apps.

PS: I also have Windows Phone, UWP, Windows Desktop and Mac Applications. So any analytics service that i can also use on that platforms would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing in my desktop app is sending events using the AI SKD to trace that kind of information.

When opening a form the timestamp is recorded and when the user navigates away the total time spend is calculated and send using a TrackMetric event.

See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/

The metric name could be the name of the form and using custom properties (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/#properties) you can include other relevant data.

To record total time spend in the app you can reuse this idea.